# How to apply relative directory in python when imported from different module?

Tags: python

Here's the problem:

In package `main.A`, there's a module `AM` and a `config.ini` file. In `AM`, I'm using **./config.ini** to refer to this file. This just works fine.

Whereas in package `main.B`, there's another module named `BM`, which imports `main.A.AM` module. In this time, it throws that **config.ini cannot be found in /main/B/**

Could anyone tell me how to import this relatively located file in `Main.A`? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__file__` magic variable stores the path to the file it appears in.

If you put the following line in `main.A`, it will always point to a file residing in the same directory as `main.A`, regardless of the location `main.A` is imported from:

```
import os.path as osp 
osp.join(osp.dirname(__file__), 'config.ini')
```